# Android Studio adb shell Sqlite /data/data/packagename/databases/dbname.db Unable to Open Database

Tags: android, sqlite, adb, emulation

When I try access SQLite database by logging into the emulator via adb shell, it shows me this error:

```
Error: unable to open database "/data/data/packagename/databases/dbname.db": unable to open database file
```

When I try to do an ls, it shows the following:

```
ls: /data/data/packagename/databases/dbname.db: Permission denied
```

The database is working fine in the app, which I'm running on the emulator.

What could be the problem? How to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access database resource, one need to be super user and you can try to access your db after hitting `su` command and I think this will resolve your `permission denied` error.

```
adb shell
su
ls /data/data/packagename/databases/dbname.db
... do your stuff
```

Comment: Perfect. Solved the problem for me. Thanks v.much!

Comment: Done. It tried accepting earlier, but it said I must wait x minutes before accepting the answer.